# Is there any function which can be used for floating point modulo in TCL?

Tags: math, tcl

```
% set a 10.0
10.0
% set b 3.0
3.0
% puts "[expr {$a % $b}]"
can't use floating-point value as operand of "%"
```

I am getting the above error is there any way to do it in tcl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a proc in [the `::tcl::mathfunc` namespace](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/mathfunc.htm#M4):

```
proc ::tcl::mathfunc::fmod {numerator denominator} {
    return [expr {$numerator - int($numerator / $denominator) * $denominator}]
}

set a 10.0
set b 3.0
puts "[expr {fmod($a, $b)}]"   ;# => 1.0
```

---

Or, just use [the builtin `fmod` math function](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/mathfunc.htm#M19).

Comment: You could. But you don't have to, because it already exists.

Comment: D'oh! Coffee has not kicked in yet this morning.

Answer (score 2):

tcl comes with a built in [`fmod`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/mathfunc.htm#M19) math function that can be used with `expr` or as a standalone:

```
set a 10.0
set b 3.0
puts [expr {fmod($a, $b)}]
puts [::tcl::mathfunc::fmod $a $b]
```

Comment: The `fmod` function has been there for a *long* time. It was documented in the [8.3 manual](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.3/TclCmd/expr.htm) for example.

Comment: how the TCL calculates the reminder when we have $a < $b. for example ```puts [expr {fmod(35, 68)}]``` gives 35.0.

Comment: @flash I suspect it just calls the [C function of the same name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmod)